# How do I validate a form being filled out in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

So I have a new form set up it saves temporarily and all but I want it to only be able to update when it is validated otherwise show some errors. This is during the view section for the saveEdits event Any clue as to what I am doing wrong?

This is my main.js file

```
(function () {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Templates: {},
        Router: {}

    };

    // MODEL
    App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            firstName: 'first',
            lastName: 'last',
            email: 'Email',
            phone: '222',
            birthday: '07/22/1980'
       },

        validate: function (attrs) {

            if (!attrs.firstName) {
                return 'You must enter a real first name.';
            }
            if (!attrs.lastName) {
                return 'You must enter a real last name.';
            }
            if (attrs.email.length < 5) {
                return 'You must enter a real email.';
            }
            if (attrs.phone.length < 10 && attrs.phone === int) {
                return 'You must enter a real phone number, if you did please remove the dash and spaces.';
            }
            if (attrs.city.length < 2) {
                return 'You must enter a real city.';
            }
        },

        initialize: function() {
             this.on('invalid', function (model, invalid) {
                console.log(invalid);
            });
        }

    });

    //var userModel = new App.Models.User();

    //VIEW
    App.Views.User = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#user',
        //model: userModel,
        //tagName: 'div',
        //id: 'user',
        //className: 'userProfile',
        //template: _.template($("#userTemplate").html()),
        //editTemplate: _.template($("#userEditTemplate").html()),


        initialize: function (){

        },

        render: function() {
            this.template = Handlebars.compile($("#userTemplate").html());
            this.editTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#userEditTemplate").html());

            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events: {
            'click button.edit': 'editProfile',
            'click button.save': 'saveEdits',
            'click button.cancel': 'cancelEdits'
        },

        editProfile: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.editTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));

        }, 

        saveEdits: function () {
            var form = $(this.el).find('form#updateUser');
            this.model.set({

                firstName : form.find('.firstName').val(),
                lastName : form.find('.lastName').val(),
                email: form.find('.email').val(),
                phone: form.find('.phone').val(),
                birthday: form.find('.birthday').val()

            });

            this.model.validate();

            this.render();

        },

        cancelEdits: function() {
            this.render();
        }

    });
    //start history service
    Backbone.history.start();

    var user = new App.Views.User({model: new App.Models.User()});
    user.render();
})();
```

It works fine until I insert the this.model.validate and an error shows up stating this: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call `validate` explicitly -- [it's meant called by the Backbone framework](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

> By default validate is called before save, but can also be called before set if {validate:true} is passed.

So to fix the code in the OP, use `validate: true` in the call to [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set):

```
this.model.set({ 
    firstName : form.find('.firstName').val(),
    // ...
}, { validate: true });
```

---

<sub>Note that, if you wanted to call validate, then you have to pass it the `attrs` parameter, as in `this.model.validate(this.model.toJSON());`</sub>

Comment: Thanks, do you know why I am getting this error? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined am I calling it wrong in the validate function in my models?

Comment: @Lion789 well, there is no "city" for example, so you can't call `city.length` without getting an error.  You need to check for that.  As in, `if (typeof attr.city == "undefined" || attr.city.length < 2)`.

Comment: I actually did this and it seems to work,  phone: {
             length: 10
             if(length <10) {
              return 'You must enter ';
             }
            }

Comment: One small recommendation - I'd suggest binding to the 'submit' event on the form rather than the 'click' on the save button (if your HTML is using a `<form>` tag), just in case the user's browser has a way of submitting the form without explicitly raising a 'click' event on that button.